# unit testing express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, unit-testing, chai

I have the following middleware function in my express app,

```
const { getEmployerId } = require("./employerApi");

const setEmployerDetails = (employerId) => {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        getEmployerId(req, res, next, employerId);
    }
}

module.exports = setEmployerDetails
```

I wanting to unit test this middleware, but I am not sure how, the function basically returns whatever the API returns, the API is already unit tested. How would I go about unit testing this function with something like chai?

So far I have,

```
describe('setEmployerDetails`, () => {
   it('should be a function', () => expect(setEmployerDetails).to.be.a('function'));
   it('should take 1 argument', () => expect(setEmployerDetails.length).to.equal(1));
});`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should stub `getEmployerId` function use [Link Seams](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/). Then, test it as usual.

E.g.

`mw.js`:

```js
const { getEmployerId } = require('./employerApi');

const setEmployerDetails = (employerId) => {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    getEmployerId(req, res, next, employerId);
  };
};

module.exports = setEmployerDetails;
```

`mw.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('66798873', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const getEmployerId = sinon.stub();
    const setEmployerDetails = proxyquire('./mw', {
      './employerApi': { getEmployerId },
    });
    const mReq = {};
    const mRes = {};
    const mNext = sinon.stub();
    setEmployerDetails(123)(mReq, mRes, mNext);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(getEmployerId, {}, {}, mNext, 123);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
  66798873
    ✓ should pass (2712ms)


  1 passing (3s)

----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File            | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files       |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 employerApi.js |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |                   
 mw.js          |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```